# Graylog2 Web-Interface on Ubuntu Crashing Rack?

Tags: ubuntu, graylog2

I have been trying to install graylog2 on ubuntu 12.10. I finally got the server going, but I seem to be having problems with the web interface. When I start Passenger, and then visit 0.0.0.0:3000, I'm getting an error with rack:

```
[ pid=17089 thr=5814240 file=utils.rb:176 time=2013-03-17 16:14:31.439 ]: *** Exception NoMethodError in PhusionPassenger::Rack::ApplicationSpawner (undefined method `values' for nil:NilClass) (process 17089, thread #<Thread:0x00000000b16fc0>):
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/mongoid-2.4.5/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:83:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
```

I have not been able to move past this point, and was wondering if anyone had any suggestions as to what could be causing this. I'm following the guide from the graylog website.

Comment: Same here... Ubuntu 13.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to specify the proper environment.

I've got this error and was able to solve it passing the environment option.

```
script/rails server -e production
```